# Where to dispose IDisposable members of an ASP.net page?

Tags: .net, asp.net, idisposable

What is the best practice to dispose `IDisposable` members of an ASP.net page?

Should I, ...

- use the `Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)` event
- override the `void Dispose()` method of the `Control` class
- something else ...

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally there shouldn't really be any.  In an ASP.NET page you should really use the `using(...) { ... }` construct, which disposes objects immediately.  If you have members of your page that need disposing, that's probably an indication of bad design, so consider putting those objects in things like session state or the cache instead.

Any postback should only invoke one public method on the page, so there should be no need to share state other than passing as method parameters (I suppose there's always the IoC container argument if you're using one, but then all bets are off as WebForms isn't really aimed at IoC usage).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your assertion that holding a disposable member is an indication of bad design?

Comment: As members of the page? Any postback should only invoke one public method on the page, so there should be no need to share state other than passing as method parameters (I suppose there's always the IoC container argument if you're using one, but then all bets are off as WebForms isn't really aimed at IoC usage).

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely have to have IDisposable objects as members of the page then I would go with during the Unload phase:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx